# Tcl: command name creation

Tags: tcl

I have a line in my tcl code like this:

Application/BitTorrent set seqNo_ $opt(seqNo)

..I have an OTcl class name "Application/BitTorrent", I get this ERROR...

invalid command name "Application/BitTorrent"
    while executing
"Application/BitTorrent set seqNo_ $opt(seqNo)"
can anybody tell me the syntax or the way to create  a command in tcl?

thanks!

Comment: I found some OTcl docs at http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/otcl/README.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tcl: Invalid command name error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222733/tcl-invalid-command-name-error)

Answer (score 1):

No sure about OTcl Syntax, but usually for the OO style Tcl extensions it would be like:

```
Application/BitTorrent myapp
myapp set seqNo_ $opt(seqNo)
```

first creating an instance of class Application/BitTorrent and than using the set method on it. But your error indicates there might be some problem with your class, e.g. its not visible or something like that. You should check with introspection commands like [info commands] or the appropriate OTcl versions if the class really exists and is named like you expect it.

Comment: OTcl syntax is pretty much the same as XOTcl (which is derived from OTcl, but with more stuff added).